# Modal works after second click

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm using Reactstrap Modal for registration. First time clicked on button 'sign up' works fine and the modal is opened. After closing the modal and opening it again, it doesn't work on the first click, only after it, so I have to make double click to open. If I put all code in one file, my Home.tsx, then it's working fine. But I want Modal (in this case Register.tsx) and Home.tsx to be in separate files. After separating in 2 files this issue is appearing. How can I fix this?

Here is code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-star-27wir?file=/src/Home.tsx

Comment: I would guess you're not setting the `modalSignUp` back to `false` correctly when you close the modal. I don't know what the `toggle={props.toggle}` does on your `<Modal>` component, but that seems like a good place to start debugging. (Edit: I tried swapping `toggle` for `onClosed` and it seems like what you need)

Comment: Any reason why you separate the model open/close state in two places? You could have only one state in `Home` and pass `setModalSignUp` to `Register`

Answer (score 2):

Don't duplicate states. Use the `toggle` value and callback in `Register` component as you are already passing it.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-strap-model-issue-fix-7buff?file=/src/Register.tsx)

**Code snippet**

```js
function Register(props: any) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState<string>("");

  // const [modal, setModal] = useState(props.modal); // no need of this
  //console.log(modal);

  const validateSignUp = () => {
    if (firstName === "") {
      props.toggle(true);
    } else {
      props.toggle(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={props.modal} toggle={props.toggle}>
      <ModalHeader>Sign Up</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        <FormGroup>
          <Label>First Name</Label>
          <Input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e: any) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="success" onClick={validateSignUp}>
          Sign Up
        </Button>
        <Button
          color="danger"
          onClick={() => {
            // setModal(false); // not required
            props.toggle(false);
          }}
        >
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working except the condition `if (firstName === "")`. If I don't write anything in filed 'first name' and then click Sign In it shouldn't close the modal. Only 'Close' should close it. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When cancelling the modal by the button "cancel", you're basically updating the state of your modal component, you don't update the state of your `Home` component. What you can do is that on "Cancel" click you have a function, which does something like:

```
const onCancelModal = () => {
  setModal(false);
  props.toggle(false);
}
```

This way it's gonna work, here's a link for a complete code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-brown-io0dz?file=/src/Register.tsx

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but, it still doesn't work, same problem, i have to make 2 clicks to open modal